# In / during the period of one's infancy or childhood

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Is the usage of "period" redundant in the following phrases:

> - In / during my **infancy period**
> - In / during the **period of my infancy**
> - In / during my **childhood period**
> - In / suring the **period of my childhood**

Ngram shows no [result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+period+of+infancy%2Cmy+period+of+childhood%2Cmy+childhood+period&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) for them. Also, dictionaries describe these words as below:

**Infancy**:

> The state or **period** of being a baby.

**Childhood**:

> The **time** when someone is a child.

Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "period" is redundant in these examples. "In/During my infancy" and "In/During my childhood" are how you would say these phrases. No need to use extra words.